# Matplotlib inconvenient "reset to original view" while previously zoomed

Tags: matplotlib, interaction

Updated:

After having zoomed to a region of interest, I would like to add a scatter point without having a reset to the original view.

It occurs when I double click after having zoomed to rectangle.

Of course this is a simplification of a problem encountered as I wanted to add markers to a large image after having properly zoomed to a region of interest.

Any help welcomed

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, figsize=(4,4))
plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30, 40])
def onclick(event):
    if event.dblclick:
        plt.scatter(event.xdata, event.ydata, c='r')
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.get_current_fig_manager().toolbar.zoom()
plt.show()
```

Answer:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, figsize=(4,4))
ax.imshow([[1, 2], [5, 6]])
ax.autoscale(False)  # disable autoscaling for all future plotting functions.
def onclick(event):
    if event.dblclick:
        plt.scatter(event.xdata, event.ydata, c='r')
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.get_current_fig_manager().toolbar.zoom()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce using matplotlib v.3.3.1 and the ipympl backend

Comment: Thanks for the test. Indeed it works with this backend ipyml not with the default UI
By the way, with the 2nd exemple and with ipyml (so inside a notebook), if you press 'd', you draw a point then if you active the "Zoom to rectangle" and start the rectangle, you draw again a point. Something to add (flush ?). Any idea ?

Comment: Finally not working with ipympl. Same problem with undesired return to initial view.

Comment: Have simplified the problem. Just a double click. No more key pressed. Same annoying reset I cannot avoid. It goes back to the original view.
What am I missing ?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem comes from the autoscale features that kicks in whenever you call `plt.scatter()`. The solution is simply to disable `autoscale` (but draw the initial plot beforehand):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=1, figsize=(4, 4))
plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 3], [10, 20, 30, 40])
fig.canvas.draw()  # force draw so that the axes are autoscaled here
ax.autoscale(False)  # disable autoscaling for all future plotting functions.


def onclick(event):
    if event.inaxes and event.dblclick:
        plt.scatter(event.xdata, event.ydata, marker='o', s=10, c='r')


fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you !
The ax.autoscale(False) was indeed missing. Note that with a ax.imshow(), no need to fig.canvas.draw()